# How to Access an Object from a Data model (NSobject) based NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, datamodel

I have an Array which executed and combined multiple QBUUser users below.

2018-01-24 12:05:33.095197+0400 samplechat[70177:6634702] COMBINEDARRAY(

```
  "
  [QBUUser]:
  ID:25957858
  created at:2017-04-04 11:06:17 +0000
  updated at:2017-12-18 06:03:52 +0000
  externalUserID:0
  blobID:0
  facebookID:(null)
  twitterID:(null)
  twitterDigitsID:(null)
  full name:rothessa balinario  sevilla
  email:rothessa.sevilla@aujan.com
  login:6395
  phone:3
  tags:(null)
  lastRequestAt:2017-12-18 06:06:22 +0000
  customData:default.png
  website:http://hr team coordinator",
    "
  [QBUUser]:
  ID:26229973
  created at:2017-04-11 13:00:53 +0000
  updated at:2018-01-24 08:04:12 +0000
  externalUserID:0
  blobID:0
  facebookID:(null)
  twitterID:(null)
  twitterDigitsID:(null)
  full name:dalila  isabelle   safir
  email:dalila.safir@aujan.com
  login:9937
  phone:2
  tags:(null)
  lastRequestAt:2018-01-24 08:04:12 +0000
  customData:default.png
  website:http://human resources director",
    "
  [QBUUser]:
  ID:26429684
  created at:2017-04-16 06:42:44 +0000
  updated at:2018-01-22 11:01:24 +0000
  externalUserID:0
  blobID:0
  facebookID:(null)
  twitterID:(null)
  twitterDigitsID:(null)
  full name:fawaz al  omran
  email:fawaz.alomran@aujan.com
  login:9129
  phone:3
  tags:(null)
  lastRequestAt:2018-01-22 11:01:24 +0000
  customData:default.png
  website:http://brand manager - vimto cordial",
    "
  [QBUUser]:
  ID:26472195
  created at:2017-04-17 06:24:44 +0000
  updated at:2018-01-23 08:22:06 +0000
  externalUserID:0
  blobID:0
  facebookID:(null)
  twitterID:(null)
  twitterDigitsID:(null)
  full name:ahmet  kursat  kaymaz
  email:kursat.kaymaz@aujan.com
  login:9625
  phone:3
  tags:(null)
  lastRequestAt:2018-01-23 08:22:06 +0000
  customData:default.png
  website:http://category manager",
```

So I wanted to access the fullname and load into my tableview method ex - user.fullname [indexpath.row].. but I don't know a method to access and load allusers into my table view.

I tried following method and without indexpath.row so it's loading the last user only to the tableview.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return multiCombinedArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //  UserTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"contactUserCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"UserTableViewCellIdentifier";
    ChatUserTableViewCell *chatUsersCell = (ChatUserTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(chatUsersCell == nil)
    {
        chatUsersCell = [[ChatUserTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

  //  chatUsersCell.chatUserFullName.text = multiCombinedArray

    for(QBUUser *user in multiCombinedArray)
    {
        chatUsersCell.chatUserFullName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",user.fullName];

    }
  return chatUserCell;
}
```

Please help me quickly to access the fullname and load all name into the table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to cycle over your `multiCombinedArray`, accessing with the `indexPath.row` will be enough, so

**replace this**

```
for(QBUUser *user in multiCombinedArray)
    {
        chatUsersCell.chatUserFullName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",user.fullName];

    }
```

**by this**

```
   QBUUser * user = multiCombinedArray[indexPath.row];
   chatUsersCell.chatUserFullName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",user.fullName];
```

Comment: Thank's I missed the simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
QBUUser * user = multiCombinedArray[indexPath.row];
chatUsersCell.chatUserFullName.text = user.fullName
```